# Group users in sets of 10

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm wondering if there is a good module - and if there is I'd also like some pointers - on how to put users into groups.

Basically for every 10 people who are added, I'd like them to be added to a group which is assigned a number. There is also one facilitator assigned to each group, who may be assigned to multiple groups. I also need to add/remove people from the group at will and swap members between groups.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a vocabulary named 'User Groups'. Goto admin/config/people/accounts/fields and add a taxonomy term field for the user.

```
<?php    
function mymodule_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {

$termname = int($account->uid / 10);
if(!empty(taxonomy_get_term_by_name(termname)){
  $newterm = new stdClass();
  $newterm->name = $termname;
  $newterm->vid = 5; the vid of the vocabulary 'User group which you should create manually'
  taxonomy_term_save(($newterm); If the terms already exists, it will just remain the same.
  $edit['data']['field_user_group'] = $newterm->tid;
}
?>
```

So for every user in the range of multiples of 10 it will assign a single term. Eg for users with uid from 0 to 9 will be assigned with the term name 0, 10-19 with 1 and so on.

Since all users are just tagged with a name for the group, from the admin interface. For each of these tags you can also assign a user.

Note : The code is just for the concept, it is not exact or tested.